# Determine the optimal cruise control options

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

A cruise control has 3 different options to move the handle to set the speed you want to drive with.

- Towards you: Adds 1 speed.
- Upwards: Increases speed to the next multiple of 10 (e.g. 20-->30, 32-->40)
- Downwards: Decreases speed to the next multiple of 10 (e.g. 20-->10, 32-->30)

**Input**

- 2 integers: the first is the starting speed and the second is your desired speed, both non-negative and in any form you like (array, two arguments, etc.)

**Task**

- Determine the optimal way of using the handle to reach the desired speed and print out the moves in the correct order.

**Rules**

- If you have the choice between pulling towards you and going upwards (like from 39 to 40) you can choose either option, but stay with whatever you choose for similar cases
- You may use any 3 different (preferably visible) symbols to distinguish between the moves in the output (T, U and D for example).
- The symbols can be seperated by new lines, spaces, etc. but don't have to be

Here are some test cases:

```
start speed, desired speed  -->  output
30, 40  -->  U
30, 43  -->  UTTT
43, 30  -->  DD
51, 39  -->  DDDTTTTTTTTT
29, 30  -->  T or U
29, 50  -->  TUU or UUU
12, 12  -->
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: For anyone who wondered, today I noticed my cruise control has actually a "hidden" button to decrease the speed by 1. I was driving wrong the entire time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>91</s> <s>84</s> 75 bytes

*Saved 4 bytes thanks to @Neil*

```
f=(s,d)=>s-d?(q=s+10-s%10)>d?s>d?0+f(s-(s%10||10),d):1+f(s+1,d):2+f(q,d):""
```

Uses `0` for `D`, `1` for `T`, and `2` for `U`.

Comment: `(s/10+1|0)*10 == (s/10|0)*10+10 == s-s%10+10`.

Comment: @Neil Thanks, that helps in another spot too!

Comment: You broke `f(37,43)` which was `2111` but your new code returns `111111`.

Comment: @Neil Fixed at a cost of 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <strike>144</strike> 139

Saved 5 bytes thanks to Kevin.

```
void o(int s,int e){int t=10,x=s/t;System.out.print(s>e?"D":s<e?x<e/t?"U":"T":"");if‌​(s!=e)o(s>e?x*t-(s%t‌​<1?t:0):s<e?x<e/t?(x‌​+1)*t:s+1:0,e);
```

Ungolfed

```
public static void optimalCruise(int start, int end){

    if(start > end) {
        System.out.print("D");
        optimalCruise(start/10*10-(start%10<1?10:0), end);
    } else if(start < end){
        if(start/10 < end/10){
            System.out.print("U");
            optimalCruise(((start/10)+1)*10, end);
        } else {
            System.out.print("T");
            optimalCruise(start+1, end);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By making two `int` variables for `10` and `s/10` you can shorten it by 5 bytes: `void o(int s,int e){int t=10,x=s/t;System.out.print(s>e?"D":s<e?x<e/t?"U":"T":"");if(s!=e)o(s>e?x*t-(s%t<1?t:0):s<e?x<e/t?(x+1)*t:s+1:0,e);`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen good catch, I'll edit it in

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 175 bytes

```
@set/as=%1,d=%2,e=d/10*10
:d
@if %s% gtr %d% echo d&set/as=~-s/10*10&goto d
:u
@if %s% lss %e% echo u&set/as=s/10*10+10&goto u
:t
@if %s% neq %d% echo t&set/as+=1&goto t
```

Fairly straightforward this time. Takes input as command-line parameters, which it saves into `s` and `d`. `e` is `d` rounded down to the previous multiple of 10. If `s` is greater than `d`, then we obviously need to invoke `d` until `s` becomes lower than `d`. Otherwise, we need to check whether `s` is lower than `e`; if so, we can invoke `u` until `s` equals `e`. At this point `s` is now between `e` and `d` and we can simply invoke `t` until we reach `d`. I looked into `for` loops but they use inclusive endpoints so would have become too verbose.

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 76 bytes

```
lambda a,b: "U"*(b//10-a//10)+"D"*(a//10-b//10+(b<a))+"T"*min(b%10,(b-a)%99)
```

Comment: `min(b%10,(b-a)%99)` wont always work, for example `(a,b)=(132,33)`

Comment: You have an extra space after `b:`

Answer (score 0):

## C, 156 bytes

```c
t,x,y;main(int s,char**a){x=(s=atoi(a[1]))/10,y=(t=atoi(a[2]))/10;if(s^t){for(;y>x;++x)puts("U");for(x+=(s-t>10);x>y;--x)puts("D");for(;t--%10;)puts("T");}}
```

Ungolfed:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int t, x, y;
int main(int s, char **a)
{
    x = (s = atoi(a[1])) / 10,
    y = (t = atoi(a[2])) / 10;

    if (s ^ t) {
        for ( ; y > x; ++x)
            puts("U");

        for (x += (s - t > 10) ; x > y; --x)
            puts("D");

        for ( ; t-- % 10; )
            puts("T");
    }
    return 0;
}
```